# Plus one button is causing JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, google-plus-one

I've read through many google plue one button not working questions on here and haven't found an answer.

I'm trying to add a google+ and a facebook button to my site. Neither one is working but I'll focus on the google button for now.

Every time is clicked it causes the following javascript error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://stephenturley.com/blog/details/7 from frame with URL https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm... ...domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

You can go to the site http://www.stephenturley.com and see the error for yourself.

Comment: The newest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: For me the google login and facebook login pages open on clicking the buttons

Comment: Once you are logged into your Google+ account, it should turn to a red exclamation point and throw an error in your java script console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, it was a simple typo. I forgot to put http in the href attribute of the button.